# Atheros QCA9565/AR9565 acting strangely (aht9k related?)

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, elementaryos

My Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565/AR9565 started to act strangely. It doesn't have any signal and sometimes don't find APs or find, but can't connect.

I read that compiling backport possibly fix the issue, but no success. I'm trying to install a backport (4.4.2-1 to be precise), but I'm getting this error when I run the `make` command:

```
  CC [M]  /home/glauco/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1/compat/main.o
In file included from /home/glauco/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1/backport-include/backport/backport.h:7:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
./include/asm-generic/qrwlock.h: In function ‘__qrwlock_write_byte’:
/home/glauco/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1/backport-include/linux/kconfig.h:25:28: error: implicit declaration of function ‘config_enabled’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 #define IS_BUILTIN(option) config_enabled(option)
                            ^
./include/asm-generic/qrwlock.h:156:26: note: in expansion of macro ‘IS_BUILTIN’
  return (u8 *)lock + 3 * IS_BUILTIN(CONFIG_CPU_BIG_ENDIAN);
                          ^
./include/asm-generic/qrwlock.h:156:37: error: ‘CONFIG_CPU_BIG_ENDIAN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  return (u8 *)lock + 3 * IS_BUILTIN(CONFIG_CPU_BIG_ENDIAN);
                                     ^
/home/glauco/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1/backport-include/linux/kconfig.h:25:43: note: in definition of macro ‘IS_BUILTIN’
 #define IS_BUILTIN(option) config_enabled(option)
                                           ^
./include/asm-generic/qrwlock.h:156:37: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  return (u8 *)lock + 3 * IS_BUILTIN(CONFIG_CPU_BIG_ENDIAN);
                                     ^
/home/glauco/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1/backport-include/linux/kconfig.h:25:43: note: in definition of macro ‘IS_BUILTIN’
 #define IS_BUILTIN(option) config_enabled(option)
                                           ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/home/glauco/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1/compat/main.o' failed
make[5]: *** [/home/glauco/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1/compat/main.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:567: recipe for target '/home/glauco/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1/compat' failed
make[4]: *** [/home/glauco/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1/compat] Error 2
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/home/glauco/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1' failed
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/glauco/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1] Error 2
Makefile.build:6: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[2]: *** [modules] Error 2
Makefile.real:88: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I'm running Elementary O.S. (Ubuntu 16 based O.S.) in a Dell Inspiron 15 (I15-5547-A10 model).